# Why don't I see my page rendered on a new react routing page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I added a new page to my application, that is identical to other working ones, but for some reason it does not render.

The page is simple:

```
export function Test() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>TEST working</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

In my App.tsx I have:

```
import './assets/App.css';
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from '@tanstack/react-query-devtools';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Layout } from './components/layout/Layout';
import { appRoutes } from './utils/appRoutes';

const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    defaultOptions: {
        queries: {
            staleTime: 5 * (60 * 1000), // 5 mins
            cacheTime: 10 * (60 * 1000), // 10 mins
        },
    },
});

function App() {
    return (
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
            <Layout>
                <Routes>
                    {appRoutes.map((route, index) => {
                        const { element, ...rest } = route;
                        return (
                            <Route key={index} {...rest} element={element} />
                        );
                    })}
                </Routes>
            </Layout>

            <ReactQueryDevtools />
        </QueryClientProvider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

My appRoutes has other identical pages, that work. However the new one does not:

```
import { Test } from '../pages/Test/Test';

export const appRoutes = [
    {
        path: baseUrl + '/SomeOtherPage',
        element: <SomeOtherPage />,
    },
    {
        path: baseUrl + '/Test',
        Element: <Test />,
    },
];
```

Going to localhost /Test renders just the layout, without the page. But other pages work correctly. I have the correct elements imported. What am I missing?

Comment: In Javascript identifiers are case-sensitive. You've a typo in the `appRoutes` configuration, `Element: <Test />` should be `element: <Test />`. Voting to close as "not reproducible or was caused by typo." Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there's a small typo in your appRoutes definition. In your route for the Test component, you've used Element with a capital "E", but in your App.tsx you're destructuring with element in lowercase (const { element, ...rest } = route;).

Comment: Just FYI, issues caused by typos are not considered of useful value to future readers. There's an entire "Vote to Close" (VTC) reason specific to it. Typically we VTC and leave a comment pointing out the typo discrepancy.